# Accessing vector in class in vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

I feel as though I'm going about this the right way, but I keep getting the error "EXC BAD ACCESS"

I have a class `person`, fairly simple with everything public.

```
class person
{
    public:
    int id;
    vector<float> scores;
    float avgscore;
};
```

I then make a vector of `person`s using the new operator

```
vector<person> *people = new vector<person>[num_persons];
```

I then attempt to access the vector inside the class `person`

```
(*people)[current_person].scores.push_back(temp);
```

where `current_person` =0, and `temp` is an integer.

Am I handling the vector the right way?

Comment: I searched around in stackoverflow and it seems that the initialization should use round brackets, i.e. new vector<person>(num_persons); but I have no idea why that is so, and it seems inconsistent. Will upvote an answer to this.

Comment: It's not inconsistent. The *only* thing that uses [] for initialization is C-style arrays. Everything else uses () (or {} for initialization lists). This makes sense since you wouldn't `delete []` a vector pointer.

Comment: @Max note: `std::map<>` uses `operator[]()` for implicit insertion after a failed-find. The rest I concur with.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
vector<person> people(num_persons);
```

and then...

```
people[current_person].scores.push_back(temp);
```

Comment: This still gets me the bad access error, albeit in a different place

Comment: Sorry guys, the problem was with a for loop overstepping the vectors bounds, a case study in sloppiness. Thanks for everything though!

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
vector<person> *people = new vector<person>[num_persons];
```

new vector only creates a vector but it contains 0 elements, accessing to `(*people)[0]` is undefined behavior which your error message `EXC BAD ACCESS` tells the story. You still need to add person element to people visiting it, e.g.

```
person p1;
people->push_back(p1);  // add element to vector
(*people)[0].scores.push_back(temp); // now you are ok to visit first element.
// don't forget to delete vector at right place
delete people;
```

As you are using vector already, you could just continue using vector for people instead of using the raw pointer.

```
std::vector<person> people;
person p1;

people.push_back(person);
people[position].scores.pus_back(score);
// don't need to worry releasing people memory anymore.
```